# Разница в объявлении функции

Tags: php

Допустим есть такая функция

```
function a()
{
    static $var = 0;
    $var++;
    return $var;
}
```

и есть такая функция

```
function &b()
{
    static $var = 0;
    $var++;
    return $var;
}
```

В чем их разница?

**Обновлено!**

В картинке ниже я попытался объяснить понимание каждого случая
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Если я как-то неправильно объяснил или понял напишите мне я поправлю (Это относится к изображению приложенному выше)

Comment: Главная разница, что за второй вариант вы получите по ушам от своего senior на code review. А вообше вам правильно ответили http://php.net/manual/ru/language.references.pass.php.

Comment: @E_p То есть будет возвращаться значение если функция декларирована с &, но пишется `$var = b();` Ссылка будет вовращаться только  если амперсанды в 2ух местах?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: «Дополнителььные вопросы напишу по мере решения текущих» — дополнительные вопросы нужно писать отдельными вопросами. Чтобы данный участниками ответ не превращался внезапно в неполный.

Comment: @VladD А что делать если вопросы которые появляются потом являются частью неполного вопроса изначально? Я специально так сделал, чтобы мне ответили последовательно, а не отвлеклись на совсем то что не нужно

Comment: @MaximPro: Задавайте вопрос полностью с самого начала. Если я, к примеру, даю ответ, а потом мне дают в вопросе следующее задание, я просто запоминаю, что данный автор вопроса хочет, чтобы ему ответили на сто вопросов вместо одного, и больше никогда ему не отвечаю.

Comment: @VladD Я так сделал впервые, просто я задавал похожий вопрос, но там мне ответили так что лучше не вспоминать. Иногда дают такие ответы, что они по факту не ответы, а реализация того что ты знал ранее. Понимаете?

Comment: @MaximPro: Если вам не понравился ответ, не плюсуйте его, делов-то! Если вам дают такой ответ на вопрос, что вы его уже знаете, то что, он от этого не становится ответом на вопрос? Авторы ответов должны догадаться до всех ваших невысказанных дополнительных условий? Если вам не подходит какое-либо решение, опишите это в вопросе с самого начала, и объясните причины. Будьте честны с людьми, люди, знаете, не любят, когда их держат за дураков.

Comment: @VladD Я вас понял, впредь буду формировать вопрос более глубоко и продуманно если на то требует мое непонимание =)
P.S А что делать в том случае когда никто не отвечает или ответы совсем дурные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что Вы спрашиваете очень легко проверить.
Краткий ответ: если НЕТ амперсанда перед вызовом функции помеченной как возврат по ссылке, то произойдет возврат по значению. Если возвращенный результат передается в функцию, которая принимает аргумент по ссылке, то передача происходит по ссылке.

http://ideone.com/4WPtNg

```
<?php
class Test {
    public $a = 111;

    function &change( $c ) {
        return $this->a;
    }
};

function secret_function( &$arg ) {
    $arg = 999;
}

$test = new Test();
$prop = $test->change();
echo( "$prop $test->a \n" );
$prop = 555;
echo( "$prop $test->a \n" );
$prop = &$test->change();
$prop = 777;
echo( "$prop $test->a \n" );
secret_function( $test->change() );
echo( "$prop $test->a \n" );
```

Результат:

```
111 111 
555 111 
777 777 
999 999
```

Comment: Вы видели картинку которую я прикрепил в конце ввиде ссылки?

Comment: К тому же я не соглашучь с вами "если НЕТ амперсанда перед вызовом функции помеченной как возврат по ссылке, то произойдет возврат по значению", а что если мы возвращаем функцию в вызов другой функции где аргумент это передача по ссылке =)
P.S По сути если в декларации есть знак амперсанда то функция возвращает ссылку на значение переменной, просто произойдет присвоение значения, на которое ссылается ссылка

Comment: А Вы видели эту картинку ? Используйте imgur.com для размещения изображений, или штатные средства SO.

Comment: "возвращаем функцию в вызов другой функции где аргумент это передача по ссылке " лучше приведите пример кода, как Вы себе это представляете.

Comment: А чем не устроила ссылка, которую я предоставил в вопросе?(Картинку видел, сам ее сделал)
Ну окей смотрите код второго примера и плюс это: `secret_function(b());` - `function secret_function(&arg){}`

Comment: Тем, что это Вконтакт, который не дает никому кроме Вас посмотреть это изображение.

Comment: Не знал! Ну я загрузил как вы просили

Comment: Картинку увидели? Что можете сказать по данному поводу?

Answer (score 4):

Если использовать амперсанд перед названием функции при её определении - результат функции будет возвращать не значение, а ссылку на переменную значения.

Comment: Допустим мы используем вариант функции где в декларации написан &, https://repl.it/DtfE/0
Вы написали что если в объявлении мы пишем &, то возвращается ссылка, а не значение, но что-то не видно =)

Comment: `function &a(&$c) {
    return $c;
}
$c = 1;
$d = &a($c);
$d++;
echo $c;` вот пример, как это используется. В результате на экране мы увидим "2", а не "1"

Comment: ну так у вас амперсанд еще и в присвоении, а не только в декларации,  так что ваше утверждение не совсем корректно! Если бы функция возвращала ссылку то в присвоении не нужен был бы амперсанд! Или я чего то не понимаю?
P.S Мануал читал

Comment: Ну у нас же вернулась ссылка, а чтобы работать с переменной по ссылке нужно использовать `&`.  Вообще согласен, запутано это всё :)

Comment: Если брать аналогию с с++, то то что вы сказали так там и работает, те же указатели =) Но это не с++ и там даже написано ссылки != указатели =) Я вот почему и спрашиваю: что будет в том случае если ссылка есть в декларации, но нет в присвоении. А если нет в присвоении, тогда что становится с "возвращаемой ссылкой". Она испаряется? Или что...данный момент не понятен

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Во втором случае функция возвращает не значение переменной, а ссылку на неё.

> Возвращение по ссылке используется в тех случаях, когда вы хотите использовать функцию для выбора переменной, с которой должна быть связана данная ссылка.

Вот более наглядный пример:

```
function &collector() {
  static $collection = array();
  return $collection;
}
$collection = &collector();
$collection[] = 'foo';
```

Comment: А вы напишите вместо `$collection = &collector();` это `$collection = collector();` Как вам?

Comment: А причём тут? Ссылка будет возвращаться только если и там и там стоит амперсанд.

Comment: То есть будет возвращаться значение если функция декларирована с &, но пишется `$collection = collector();`

Comment: Обновил вопрос.